# Create a symlink to access a directory in linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm newbie in linux and I don't now how to solve a problem. So I have a project and it's divided in 2 parts. So I have 1. `/home/project/1_partie` witch contains `test.php` and 2. `/home/project/2_partie/config/`. In the second part in `/config` directory I have 100 files :`1.php,2.php,3.php...100.php`. Now I want that in `test.php` to have access of all files from `/config`. How to do that ? Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: from `test.php` you can access files with `../1.php, ../2.php` etc.

Comment: I done an example but I want another solution beacause the path it's more big and complicated

Comment: create a symlink to the 2nd directory in you 1st (`ln -s <path_to_your_second_dir> config`), then access files by `config/1.php, config/2.php` etc

Comment: Use absolute paths? Or a combination of a basepath and adding your dynamic paths? Beware of directory traversal attacks if your dynamic path contains input from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution for your query is to create Symbolic link from /home/project/1_part to /home/project/2_partie/config directory. And in test.php you can access files from config directory as config/1.php, config/2.php likewise.

Command to create symbolic link is,
ln -sf /home/project/2_partie/config /home/project/1_part/config.

Enjoy this solution.